# AVAudioRecorder Settings did not take effect on output file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I'm using AVAudioRecorder to record and save to an audio.m4a file with these settings:

```
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
```

But when I use a software to read the attributes of audio.m4a file, I got these:

> Bitrate: 64KBps
>
> Channels: 2

So does that mean those settings above did not affect the output file, because obviously, I set its bit rate to 16 and channels to 1. Did I miss something on these settings??

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that not every setting is legal and illegal settings fail silently. So in this case a bitrate of 16 is way too low. In a sense, the system is doing you a favor; instead of barfing, it's making the recording, but it's substituting legal settings for the ones you gave.

Comment: Does that mean i cannot change the channels too?

Comment: I do not know what the legal recording settings are. And I don't know whether they are even documented. That's the whole problem.

Comment: Do you know any other Audio Recorder for iOS? Because the file size of AVAudioRecorder out put is too big for me. I need to save a 1 minute record with file size smaller than 200KB

Comment: I just wonder if there is any way to affect these settings value to the out put file. Because one of my friend made a recorder app on android with similar settings as above, and for a 1 minute record, the out put file size is just <150KB without compressing. There must be a hack/trick on iOs to accomplish this, don't you think?