# AVAudioRecorder is not respecting AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey setting

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6, avaudiorecorder

I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` in my app. Configuration looks like this:

```
....
AVAudioRecorder *internalRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:[self recordSettings] error:&error];
....

- (NSDictionary *)recordSettings __attribute__((const)) {
    return @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
             AVSampleRateKey: @(44100.0),
             AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: @(16),
             AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: @NO,
             AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: @NO};
}
```

Audio recorded on iOS 7 has 16 bit, but on iOS 8 has 32 bit. Is it a bug in iOS 8? I'm using both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 - problem is not related to Xcode version.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650161/avaudiorecorder-settings-did-not-take-effect-on-output-file?rq=1